# Distribution of the supremum of Brownian motion before hitting $-1$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

> Distribution of the supremum $M=\sup\limits_{t\leqslant\tau}W_t$ where $\tau=\inf\{t>0\mid W_t=-1\}$.

I've tried to use theorem which states 
$\sup\limits_{t\leq s}W_t \sim |W_s|$ and compute distribution of $\tau$ in order to rewrite task as
$$P(M \leq y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(\sup\limits_{t\leq s}W_t|\tau=s)p_\tau(s) \, ds $$
but it is useless because $\tau$ and $M$ are not independent.

Comment: Indeed this looks like a deadend... You might want to note instead that, for every $x>0$, $$h(x)=P\left(\sup\limits_{t\leqslant\tau}W_t\geqslant x\right)=P_0(W\ \text{hits}\ x\ \text{before}\ -1)$$ is simple and to deduce that $\sup\limits_{t\leqslant\tau}W_t$ has PDF $-h'$. Can you identify $h$?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thanks!

Comment: Then you might want to show how you solved this, for example by posting an answer below.